# Setting up a kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh, maas, kubernetes

I'm doing [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-1-10-cluster-using-kubeadm-on-ubuntu-16-04) on creating a kubernetes cluster on `Ubuntu 16.04` (I'm using 18.04 but there is no tutorial on that version yet). I finished the first three steps and everything went fine. I'm now trying to initialise the cluster with the master node in it, and I'm a bit stuck.

When I run the `master.yml` playbook with

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts ~/kube-cluster/master.yml
```

I get the following output:

```
    $ ansible-playbook -i hosts master.yml 
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.24.1) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
      RequestsDependencyWarning)

    PLAY [master] *********************************************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************
    ok: [master]

    TASK [initialize the cluster] *****************************************************************
    changed: [master]

    TASK [create .kube directory] *****************************************************************
     [WARNING]: Module remote_tmp /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp did not exist and was created with a
    mode of 0700, this may cause issues when running as another user. To avoid this, create the
    remote_tmp dir with the correct permissions manually

    changed: [master]

    TASK [copy admin.conf to user's kube config] **************************************************
    changed: [master]

    TASK [install Pod network] ********************************************************************
    changed: [master]

    PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
    master                     : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The only thing that's different compared to the tutorial is the warning about the `/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp` directory permissions. When I ssh into the master node server and run

```
kubectl get nodes
```

I get the following result:

```
NAME             STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-address  NotReady   master   16m   v1.12.2
```

Instead of the desired

```
NAME             STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master  Ready   master   16m   v1.12.2
```

I've tried to create the `tmp` directory with the ubuntu user on the server so that the warning is resolved. Unfortunately this does not change anything about the master node not being ready or having its ip address as `NAME`.

**Question:** How do I resolve this problem? How can I correctly initialise the cluster so that the master node is configured properly and is ready?

Answer (score 1):

I went through your problem and created the same instance of the issue using Vagrant to run the nodes.

Repo [here](https://github.com/Tiemma/ansible-vagrant-kubernetes-cluster), if you want to try orchestrating the node setup with vagrant

Just like you, I ran into the issue you described. It turns out flannel has a couple issues with coredns on ubuntu bionic. Flannel interfers with the coredns setup and causes it to stay in a pending state.

You can use this to check the pod state

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-bionic:~$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-576cbf47c7-hlvdj                0/1     Pending   0          52m
coredns-576cbf47c7-xmljj                0/1     Pending   0          52m
etcd-ubuntu-bionic                      1/1     Running   0          52m
kube-apiserver-ubuntu-bionic            1/1     Running   0          52m
kube-controller-manager-ubuntu-bionic   1/1     Running   0          52m
kube-proxy-gvqk4                        1/1     Running   0          52m
kube-scheduler-ubuntu-bionic            1/1     Running   0          51m
kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-5flj8   0/1     Pending   0          4m30s
```

After a couple searches, I found a link to the fix [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/980#issuecomment-403619452) on their issues page.

Install a different CNI,  they used weave there.

> kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"

More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#weave-net-from-weaveworks) from the docs

From there, your containers should start and the coredns pods should be running.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-bionic:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system 


NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-576cbf47c7-jrlbb                1/1     Running   0          11m
coredns-576cbf47c7-nfjq8                1/1     Running   0          11m
etcd-ubuntu-bionic                      1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-apiserver-ubuntu-bionic            1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-controller-manager-ubuntu-bionic   1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-proxy-nrbpx                        1/1     Running   0          11m
kube-scheduler-ubuntu-bionic            1/1     Running   0          10m
weave-net-459mw                         2/2     Running   0          10m
```

And finally

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-bionic:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ubuntu-bionic   Ready    master   14m   v1.12.2
```

Comment: worked like a charm ! Thank you  !(Ubuntu "18.04.3 LTS", kubectl version "v1.17.0")

Comment: You're very welcome.